# How to code Profile Picture file uploader like in Facebook?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

How to code Profile Picture file uploader like in Facebook?How to code Profile Picture file uploader like in Facebook?How to code Profile Picture file uploader like in Facebook?How to code Profile Picture file uploader like in Facebook?

Comment: So what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Question is more like SEO Work than searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on Update Profile picture on Facebook an xhr is generated.

So you can call a page by AJAX on the click of the button.

AJAX page you have called must show option of Upload Photo option.
Then you can divide categories for various options like Frame, Mobile Uploads etc.
which you need like Facebook.

Each of these categories data can be obtained by a for each loop on that page and can be accessed by ajax on button click of Update Picture.